# GParted Copy Filesystem really slow

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, clone, gparted

I recently got a new HDD and I am attempting to clone a Windows partition from my old one with GParted (running off live usb). What's bothering me is that GParted has been stuck on `copying filesystem` for the past half hour, which doesn't seem right. The partition is a good 1.2tb, so **I'm expecting the actual copy to take a while, *but why is it taking so long to copy the filesystem?*** It's not giving me any sort of indication of what it's doing.

Both drives are connected to my motherboard with 6GBPS SATA3 Connectors, and here are the specifications of my drives:

- **Old Drive:** 2TB Seagate Barracuda (7200rpm)
- **New Drive**: 2TB WD Red (5400rpm)

Is this normal? And if so, in your experience how long would it take to "copy tthe filesystem"?

[image]

Comment: Half an hour doesn't seem very long, considering you are copying a 1.2TB partition to another hard drive. I would just leave GParted to do it's thing. The time it takes to copy a partition to another drive will vary, depending on various factors (such as hard drive speeds, size of partition, etc).

Comment: I've given up on Gparted in the past, but it was only impatience on my part. After cancelling a few times, I eventually restarted the clone, went to bed (after making sure that my computer did not sleep while I did), and the following morning all was completed. I have no idea what it was doing (there was no disc activity, according to the LED), but I was not bothered: the job was done. Have a good night!

Comment: Alright then, thanks for the suggestion. Guess I'll try to wait it out. I just thought it was odd for it to take so long to copy the filesystem rather than the actual files themselves